# How To Make Sure DT_STR is accepted by OLE DB Destination?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database, sql-server-data-tools, sqldatatypes

I have A Data Conversion transformation that outputs to an OLE DB Destination. The connection manager for the destination connects to a SQL Server hosted on Azure. The data access mode is set to "Table or view".

There is a field called `ProductLine` in the source query that converts an `nvarchar(255)` called `DescriptionField` to a shorter code.  There have been several incarnations of this field in the source query but it presently looks like this:

```sql
CONVERT(char(2), IIF(DescriptionField = 'TypeOne', 'TO', 'TT')) AS ProductLine
```

My problem is that when I attempt to insert rows with this field into the table all rows fail. I've narrowed it down to the field described above because when this field is excluded an otherwise identical insert succeeds. However including that field leads to this message:

> String or binary data would be truncated

I'm baffled by that because the field in the destination is `char(2), not null`.

Is there a conversion I can make in the Data Conversion transformation to make this field acceptable to the destination? Alternatively I may be able to request a change to the source query.

Comment: Add a Derived Column to your data flow. Use an expression like `LEN(ProductLine)` and call the column ProductLineLength. Use your data viewer and check the values. Given the supplied formula, there's no way it's delivering anything but "TO", "TT" and *maybe* NULL.

Comment: The other thing to check is the design-time metadata.  Double click the line between the source and destination. In the "Data Flow Path Editor" that pops up, choose the Metadata tab. Sort by Name and find the ProductLine column. What Data Type and Length are specified there?

Comment: What are you doing in your data conversion task? your example only shows you converting in the SQL source

Comment: @Scotch Converting other fields. The ProductLine passes through, though if a conversion would help I could do that.

Comment: @TrevorReid What does the data type for your ProductLine field say in your metadate? double click the arrow that leads to your destination and click 'metadata' and find your field

Comment: @billinkc for ProductLine the datatype is DT_STR, Length is 2, Code Page is 1252.

Comment: In situations like this, the other thing I tend to do is have the OLE DB Destination create a new table based on what it thinks the data types and length should be. Run the data in and then compute max lengths as well as compare the actual structure

Comment: @billinkc I like that idea. In the destination's `CREATE TABLE` statement I did notice `[ProductLine] varchar(2),` instead of `char(2)`.  Does that tell us anything?  Even if it does it's unlikely I can ALTER the ultimate target table.

Comment: @TrevorReid I've never had any problems inserting DT_STR into char fields. since your SSIS data type is DT_STR, it's going to relate that to varchar. DT_STR can still be inserted into char destinations though

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this error, but I'm using SQL Server 2016 as my oleDB destination. To further troubleshoot, you can go into the 'Error Output of OLE DB Dest, ' and select redirect row under 'Error'. you could then  pull the read arrow away from the ole DB destination to a union all,multicast,or placeholder control. then right click on that and enable the data viewer to see if it's that problem row

Comment: varchar vs char won't make a difference in whether we can store a value in there - just in how much space is consumed by storing it. If you run the ETL and load to your new table, does it generate the same string or binary may be truncated error? And that is an error, yes? You run and it fails, right? SSIS will warn you that truncation *may* occur stuffing a 255 character field into a 2 character field but if the source data never contains anything over 2 characters, things are good

Comment: Please try CONVERT(char(2), LEFT(IIF(DescriptionField = 'TypeOne', 'TO', 'TT').2)) AS ProductLine

Comment: Any progress on comparing the values in the table generated by the OLE DB Destination versus the structure of the prebuilt one?

Comment: As far as I could tell al the sizes were as expected. I ended up exporting the rows as scripted inserts, dropping and recreating the table (same structure), re-inserting the rows via SSMS.  Afterward the package worked.  @billinkc. I assume there had been something wrong with the table all along, or perhaps some mishap from a previous migration?

Comment: Hard to tell at this point but glad the situation is resolved